# PKCS11Exception when creating MAC instance on OpenJDK 11 in fips mode

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#11, fips, nss

I’m trying to run the following code on an Oracle Linux Server 8.3, with openjdk 11.0.9 in fips mode.

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32;

public class TestMAC {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Base32 codec = new Base32();
        byte[] decodedKey = codec.decode("TESTKEY1234567890_TESTKEY1234567890");
        SecretKeySpec signKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, "HmacSHA1");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(signKey);
        System.out.println("Created");
    }
}
```

The following exception is thrown from the mac.init(signKey) line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Could not create key
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.createKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:285)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.convertKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:190)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.convertKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:122)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11Mac.engineInit(P11Mac.java:197)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Mac.chooseProvider(Mac.java:366)
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Mac.init(Mac.java:435)
    at com.testing.TestMAC.main(TestMAC.java:15)
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_ATTRIBUTE_VALUE_INVALID
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_CreateObject(Native Method)
    at jdk.crypto.cryptoki/sun.security.pkcs11.P11SecretKeyFactory.createKey(P11SecretKeyFactory.java:280)
    ... 6 more
```

My nss.fips.cfg files contents are:

```
Name = NSSFIPS
nssLibraryDirectory = /usr/lib64
nssSecmodDirectory = /etc/pki/nssdb
nssDbMode = readOnly
nssModule = fips
```

I’m not clear if this is related to this bug (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1964109) or not and I’m not sure what to do to resolve it or troubleshoot it any further.

I’d appreciate any ideas you all may have.

Comment: Hi David, did you find a workaround or solution for this? I am also having similar issue- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68388083/keystore-setkeyentry-not-working-in-fips-mode

Comment: Hi Paul, I did find a bit of a workaround but I'm not sure it will help with your issue.  I was doing TOTP work and needed to create a HMAC-SHA1 hash, so instead of using the javax.crypto package I used bouncy castle to generate the hash.

Comment: I have the same issue, and found if FIPS enabled, it will have similar issue, so have to disable fips